# How to define a REST endpoint for POST requests, expecting single items and lists?

Tags: rest, post, http-post, api-design

In the API, I'm working on, there is an endpoint, that should be inter alia requested via POST to create a single item like

```
{
    "title": "foo title",
    "description": "foo description"
}
```

but also a list of items like

```
{
    "items": [
        {
            "title": "foo title",
            "description": "foo description"
        },
        {
            "title": "bar title",
            "description": "bar description"
        },
        {
            "title": "buz title",
            "description": "buz description"
        }
    ]
}
```

Is it REST-conform, that an endpoint expects (and handles as valid) multiple types of input (a single item and also a list)? Or should only a list be defined as valid input in such a case?

**How to meet the requirement and design this endpoint correctly?**

Answer (score 1):

I can't see any issues not to do that. In fact, it's up to you to manage the provided content.

Perhaps could you provide a simple array of elements for the list of items:

```
[
    {
        "title": "foo title",
        "description": "foo description"
    },
    {
        "title": "bar title",
        "description": "bar description"
    },
    {
        "title": "buz title",
        "description": "buz description"
    }
]
```

I wrote something about this at this url: https://templth.wordpress.com/2015/05/14/implementing-bulk-updates-within-restful-services/. See section "Implementing bulk adds".

Hope it helps you,
Thierry